# Prevent old style function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, eslint

I want to forbid old style function declarations and non-binding method declarations:

```
function f1() { ... }
const f2 = function() { ... }
class C {
  f3() { ... }
}
```

Instead arrow-style constants and fields must be used:

```
const f1 = () => { ... };
class C {
  f3 = () => { ... };
}
```

Is it possible with ESLint or some plugin?

Comment: Making them all forbidden will bite you in the ass one day. But would like to know for “standalone” functions too.

Comment: DO NOT USE ARROW FUNCTIONS IN CLASSES. It makes it impossible to inherit from classes. If you intend to use inheritance you MUST USE REGULAR FUNCTIONS. If you never want to use inheritance then this is OK

Comment: What's wrong with inheritance and arrow functions? I don't use it much but I didn't have problems yet.

Comment: @Koen. I can always explicitly opt-out from this restriction when this makes sense. But generally I've found that arrow functions prevent some bugs related to `this`, so I'm using them whenever possible.

Comment: What do you mean with "some bugs related to `this`"?

Comment: Methods usually work with `this`. If I'm using method as a callback, its `this` variable will be set to some nonsense like `window`, so it won't work as expected, I must explicitly call `bind`. If I'm using arrow function value, its `this` automatically set to correct object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this out](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback), there is a `prefer-arrow-callback` rule.